# GameObject does not move after transform.position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a GameObject that I try to move. For the GameObject I created a new class and this class has a function UpdatePosition(). In this function I update the transform.position of the GameObject and if I log the transform.position of the object, the console writes the newly updated position. However, in the game and scene view in Unity the object does not move. I call the function every tick via an Update function and this works since the Debug.Log outputs to the console every tick. Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

```
public class ActiveObjects
{
    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject theMovingObject;
    [SerializeField]
    public Transform startPosition;
    [SerializeField]
    public Transform endPosition;

    [NonSerialized]
    private float speed = 10.0f;
    [NonSerialized]
    public float startTime;
    [NonSerialized]
    public float journeyLength;

    // Sets new position of theMovingObject
    public void UpdatePosition()
    {
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        theMovingObject.transform.position =    Vector3.MoveTowards(theMovingObject.transform.position, endPosition.position, step);
        Debug.log(theMovingObject.transform.position);
    }

}
```

The output of in the console is the position which theMovingObject should have, but does not have in the game/scene view.

Comment: I think that MoveTowards only works in the Update(). Can you try?

Comment: Nope, that does not work. And I guess if MoveTowards would only work in Update(), wouldn't that mean that the values that get logged also not change? Should I attached something like a rigidbody or I don't know what to my object to make it possible to move?

Comment: You're not inheriting from `MonoBehaviour`, so this class isn't attached to any game object. Care to show how and from where you call `UpdatePosition()`?

Comment: @Galandil I call it from another one of my classes in its update function. This other class does inherit from MonoBehaviour. Code:    public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour { void Update()
    {
        foreach(ActiveObjects cue in cueList)
        {
            float step = cue.speed * Time.deltaTime;
            cue.UpdatePosition();
        }

    }}

Comment: @Jorism, it's better if you edit your post with the code. Code does not present well in comments.

Comment: Is your object by any chance flagged as `static` in the editor ? If yes, any modification to the transform at runtime will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3();
newPosition.x = *;
newPosition.y = *;
newPosition.z = *;
transform.position = newPosition;
```

And if you want Decimal numbers, do this:

```
newPosition.x = 0.5f;
```

*Any number

Just to explain:

Vector2 = X, Y

Vector3 = X,Y,Z

Get it? If it doesn't work, just write a comment at this answer. Greetings, Tjovo studios.